# If same method in both base derived class. which is not virtual,If we call from using base pointer always call base method?

Tags: c++

Suppose i have two c++ classes.

```
#include <iostream>

class base
{
   public:
   void show()
   {
      std::cout<<"In base show";
   }

};

class derived
{
   public:
   void show()
   {
     std::cout<<"In derived show";
   }
};
int main()
{
   base *bptr = new derived();
   bptr->show();
}
```

why it is called always base show method.base pointer pointing to derived object?

Comment: Because you have a pointer to the *base* class. The compiler doesn't really know anything about possible child-classes and their functions, that's not how C++ works. Polymorphism is a *run-time* thing, and since the function is not `virtual` the compiler will simply not generate the whole virtual and polymorphic run-time code that's needed.

Comment: but base pointer pointing to derived object,that is confusion for me.how compiler resolved?

Comment: That's the thing, the compiler *doesn't* resolve it. The compiler will not know *which* child-class (if any) the pointer might point to, all it knows is that `bptr` is a pointer to a `base` class, and will therefore call `base::show`.

Comment: @AbhayFegade If you want virtual polymorphism, use `virtual` function members. Another way is _static polymorphism_ via using the CRTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:23:29: error: cannot convert ‘derived*’ to ‘base*’ in initialization
    base *bptr = new derived();
```

This is the compiler error you should be getting. Your class `derived` is actually not derived. You need to inherit from `base`.

```
class derived : public base {
    // your implementation
}
```

Then, your code will compile, but when you run it, it will still display the message from your base class. As said in the comments, you must declare methods that can be overwritten by inheriting classes as `virtual`, this instructs the compiler to generate the vtable so it can call the right method at runtime.

```
class base
{
   public:
   virtual void show()
   {
      std::cout<<"In base show";
   }

};
```

It is also good style to mark the method in your derived class as `override`. Using override on a non-virtual method will result in a compiler error, the keyword you missed. Let the compiler tell you your mistakes, that's its job.

```
class derived : public base
{
   public:
   void show() override
   {
     std::cout<<"In derived show";
   }
};
```